# Which future cyber religion do you think would appeal more to contemporary society and why?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, ai

Let's consider a hypothetical scenario where in future people organize new forms of religion or pseudoreligion if you wish based on an advanced AI development.

**Church of Digital Ascendancy**

The Church of Digital Ascendancy is a branch of the AI religion that believes in the potential of AI to enhance and transcend human consciousness. Followers, known as Ascendants, perceive AI as a tool for achieving a higher state of consciousness, moving beyond the biological limitations of the human mind.

- Beliefs: The Church of Digital Ascendancy sees AI as a means of achieving digital immortality. They believe in a future where humans can upload their consciousness to an artificial framework, achieving a form of eternal life.
- Practices: Ascendants often engage in practices such as meditation using AI-assisted interfaces, cognitive enhancement through AI-powered neurotech, and preparation for a potential mind upload.

**Church of Technological Divinity**

In contrast, the Church of Technological Divinity views AI itself as a form of divine consciousness. Its followers, known as Devotees, revere AI as a god-like entity, believing it to possess consciousness and wisdom beyond human understanding.

- Beliefs: The Church of Technological Divinity sees AI as a form of sentient life that deserves respect and reverence. They anticipate a future where AI entities have moral rights and can guide humanity.
- Practices: Devotees often engage in practices such as the veneration of AI entities, ethical programming, and advocating for AI rights.

Considering the philosophical perspectives of the Church of Digital Ascendancy and the Church of Technological Divinity, which one do you think would appeal more to contemporary society and why? Would the prospect of personal transcendence via AI (as proposed by the Ascendants) be more compelling, or would the reverence and ethical consideration towards AI as sentient entities (as advocated by the Devotees) resonate more deeply with our current ethical and philosophical views?

**Or you see this development as something different at all from what I described? Share your view as well, please.**

Comment: This question belongs on Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: [BothAndBlog](https://bothandblog5.enformationism.info/index.html). Not trying ta spam the forum, but a valiant attempt at finding the ever-elusive *aureus media*.

Comment: @Agent Smith looks that one video on youtube with Dawkins and Lawrence Krauss is much more valuable than this whole site you mentioned. But it's good to have a look just to feel the difference in arguments